# Prove Bounded Operator on $C_\lambda^* (\Gamma)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, gelfand-representation, completely-positive-maps

I have a question in Haagerup's paper "An Example of a Non-Nuclear C*-algebra, which has the Metric Approximation Property", namely in Lemma 1.1.

Let $\Gamma$ a discrete (countable) group and $\varphi$ a positive definite function on $\Gamma$, the goal is to show that exists a unique, completely positive operator $M_\varphi: C_\lambda^* (\Gamma) \xrightarrow{} C_\lambda^* (\Gamma)$ such that for all $x \in \Gamma$,
$$
M_\varphi \lambda_x = \varphi(x)\lambda_x.
$$
The proof goes as follows: Let $(\pi,H,\xi)$ be the GNS triple associated to $\varphi$ and fix a Hilbert basis $\{e_n: n \in \mathbb N\}$. For every $n$, define the function $a_n: \Gamma \xrightarrow{} \mathbb C$ by
$$
a_n(x) = \langle \pi(x)e_n , \xi \rangle.
$$
We can prove that for all $x \in \Gamma$,
$$
 \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb N} |a_n(x)|^2 = \varphi(e).
$$
Moreover, it is easily seen through the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality that $a_n \in \ell^\infty(\Gamma)$, thus viewing that as multiplication operators acting on $\ell^2(\Gamma)$, define for $f \in  C_\lambda^* (\Gamma) \subseteq B(\ell^2(\Gamma))$,
$$
M_\varphi f = \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb N} a_n f a_n^*.
$$
My question is why is this operator well defined? I have tried applying to an element $b \in \ell^2(\Gamma)$ and use inequalities like the Minkowski integral one and fubini but always arrive at a divergent series.

In the paper Haagerup just says "because the operator $\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb N} a_n a_n^* = \varphi(e)\cdot$ is bounded".

Comment: It is as Haagerup said, this follows from $\sum_n a_na_n^\ast$ being bounded. Indeed, if $f$ is positive, then $\sum_n a_nfa_n^\ast \leq ||f|| \sum_n a_na_n^\ast$ is bounded. Since positive elements span the $C^\ast$-algebra, you obtain the result.

Comment: @DavidGao why does that inequality follow from the positivity of $f$? Thank you very much for your rely.

Comment: Generally, if $f \leq g$, then $afa^\ast \leq aga^\ast$ as $aga^\ast - afa^\ast = a(g - f)a^\ast \geq 0$. Since $f \leq ||f||$, we have $afa^\ast \leq ||f||aa^\ast$. This holds for all self-adjoint $f$. I'm restricting to positive $f$ because then $\sum_n a_nfa_n^\ast \leq ||f||\sum_n a_na_n^\ast$ actually implies $\sum_n a_nfa_n^\ast$ is bounded. Also, in that case you can actually show that $\sum_n a_nfa_n^\ast$ converge (in SOT) in the first place, by noting the sequence of partial sums is an increasing sequence of positive elements bounded above by $||f||\sum_n a_na_n^\ast$.